# channel subscriptioncount returned via youtube api is different from actual value in youtube channel

Tags: api, youtube-api

I am using youtube v3 API

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCo-3ThNQmPmQSQL_L6Lx1_w&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

for channelID `UCo-3ThNQmPmQSQL_L6Lx1_w`, in statistics I can see that this API returns subscription count as 115475 where as when I open this channel in youtube, I can see subscription count as 115449. Please let me know why API result is different than actual channel information in youtube.

Looking for positive response soon.

Answer (score 0):

This is because widget, and the web site is using cached numbers and updating periodically.

On the other hand, you get most up-to-date numbers from API.